# How to view Physical volume files?

Tags: server, lvm, volume-control

I have the two physical volumes:

```
PV         VG           Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
/dev/sdb1  main_storage lvm2 a--  74.53g    0 
/dev/sdc1  main_storage lvm2 a--  74.53g    0
```

And this physical volumes are mounted to the volume group:

```
VG           #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
main_storage   2   1   0 wz--n- 149.05g    0
```

And this volume group is mounted to `/data` dir.
When I move to the `/data` dir I can view my files.
How do I can find out in what physical volume(disk) each file was stored?
In other words how to view files of each physical volume?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `pvdisplay` command?

Comment: yes. I tried. but this command displays only the information about the PV

Comment: but I need to view the files of the PV

Comment: You mean the physical device that a specific file is stored? Depending on your configuration it may be split and some of it may be on `sdb1` while the remaining part may be on `sdc1`.

Comment: Yes. What the physical device that a specific file is stored. I mean it. File may be split? The first part of file may be on sdb1 and the second on the sdc1? Or you mean some files may be on different physical devices? Configuration type is linear.

Comment: I haven't used it, but maybe `debugfs` is the answer...